# Auto increment ID on a Swing form resets every time the application is launched

Tags: java, swing, auto-increment

I have a small challenge am using the code below to generate ID's for my incident report app that am developing with Swing...

```
private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
private  int staffId;
staffId = counter.incrementAndGet();
txtReferenceNumber.setText("SHE-0000"+ staffId);
```

This works fine. The problem is that the counter resets to zero each time the application is open that after exiting the app.

How to save the state of the counter such that each time the app is open is reads from the last saved stated and continues thereafter? That is, if the last saved `incidentNumber` was `SHE0010`  when the app is on its should continue from there instead of reverting back to `SHE0001`

Comment: Save the value in a database or a file.

Comment: You should certainly use an AUTO_INCREMENT database column for this.

Answer (score 0):

everytime you close the app it comes out of the RAM. Either you have to save the state of the app by keeping the background process open and the state will be lost when restarting. However you can save the data on harddisk and take the value from it everytime you open the app.. Probably the best solution is to save it on the file. e.g. text file.